# Ho to make complex query GraphQL with sgqlc

Tags: python-3.x, graphql, web-api-testing

I faced with difficult problem making graphql query with sgqlc.operation library. I've tried to make Cannot find an answear, I'm so stuck :(

I need to make query like this:

```
mutation {
  addEntities(
    organization: "НИУ", 
    data: {
    limitedaccess: [
      {
        value: "https://hiddennnadmin.com",
      }
    ]
  }) {
    data {
      id
      source
      value
      state
    }
    rejections {
        key {
          id
        },
        rejections {
          id
          message
        }
      }
  }
}
```

My GraphQl schema that I automaticly added with sgqlc:

```
class Mutations(sgqlc.types.Type):
    add_entities = sgqlc.types.Field(AdditionResponseServiceEntityResponseBase, graphql_name='addEntities', args=sgqlc.types.ArgDict((
        ('organization', sgqlc.types.Arg(String, graphql_name='organization', default=None)),
        ('data', sgqlc.types.Arg(sgqlc.types.non_null(UpsertDataInput), graphql_name='data', default=None))`


class AdditionResponseServiceEntityResponseBase(sgqlc.types.Type):
    data = sgqlc.types.Field(sgqlc.types.non_null(sgqlc.types.list_of(sgqlc.types.non_null(ServiceEntity))), graphql_name='data')
    rejections = sgqlc.types.Field(sgqlc.types.non_null(sgqlc.types.list_of(sgqlc.types.non_null('Rejection'))), graphql_name='rejections')


class UpsertDataInput(sgqlc.types.Input):
    __schema__ = schema
    __field_names__ = ('massmedia', 'socialmedia', 'mobileapplication', 'socialaccount', 'fraudlentresource', 'database', 'limitedaccess', 'sharingplatform')
    massmedia = sgqlc.types.Field(sgqlc.types.list_of(sgqlc.types.non_null(MassMediaRequestInput)), graphql_name='massmedia')
 
...block of code with other __field_names__
```

My code to construct query here:

```
def add_entities(services: str, values: str):
        """Query to create entities"""
        op = Operation(Mutations)
        op.add_entities(organization='ORGNAME')
        op.add_entities(data={f"{services}": [{'value': values}]})
        op.add_entities.data()
        op.add_entities.rejections()
        print(op)
```

Arised ValueError. So it seems like it want to extract data from AdditionResponseServiceEntityResponseBase, but for my query I need data as field in Mutations.add_entities.data:

```
ValueError: add_entities already have a selection addEntities(organization: "ORGNAME") {
  data {
    source
    state
    hidden
    stateUpdated
    service
    id
    updated
    details
    subService
    value
    created
    description
    tags
  }
}. Maybe use __alias__ as param?
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, probably might be helful for somebody! Just put all of your arguments in one invocation `op.add_entities(organization=..., data=...)`, then add your fields.

```
def add_entities(services, values):
        op = Operation(Mutations)
        op.add_entities(organization=config.user_organization, data={f"{services}": [{'value': values}]})
        op.add_entities.data()
        op.add_entities.rejections()
```